# Converting rmarkdown to pdf using a template

Tags: r, r-markdown, pdf-generation

I am working on a markdown document using the option from template and then a template that our professor gave us, called lab_report. I want to create a pdf but i dont have the option "knit to pdf", which is weird. Can anybody help? Thanks!!

This is what i got so far:

title: "Lab 1"
author: "Giusi Adragna"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: openintro::lab_report

I wanted to use the option 'knit to pdf' but i cannot find it anymore.

Comment: Using `openintro::lab_report` you can only create HTML reports. It does not support `pdf` or `word` or ...